# How can I prevent users deleting the pointer of a container member?

Tags: c++

I have an API that returns a constant list of objects which represent non-copyable operating system resources. I want the list to be an absolute source of truth as to the state of the resources. If an application took a copy and manipulated the copy then the corresponding state change of the resource would not be reflected in the object stored in the list, so I want to prevent this, and also prevent removing resources from the list.

I have deleted various constructors and assignment operators and am so far happy that the user can only reference list members, and the list is itself a reference and I have satisfied myself that the list itself cannot be copied. I am also happy that pop_back() and similar calls fail because the list is returned as `const`.

However, this code compiles and potentially breaks the list.

```
const std::vector<MyClass> &list = MyClass::GetList();
const MyClass              *test = &(list[0]);

delete test;
```

I know that you would have to be a muppet to do something like this, but in my 25 year career I have seen many such muppets earning good salaries (I suppose) as professional software engineers.

I'm pretty sure that this would cause a crash of some sort, or some other undefined and potentially application breaking behaviour that will, hopefully, be caught before the code goes into production. Hopefully. Hahahaha.

How can I make this code generate a compile error or otherwise smack said muppets over the back of the head with their own stupidity?

Comment: The problem with attempting to create an idiot-proof API is that the various "become an instant C++ uberhacker overnight by solving our coding puzzles" web sites will immediately produce a crop of better idiots. It's a losing battle. P.S. It is not easy deleting a pointer to a `const` object. I would have to intentionally turn myself into an idiot. I don't like doing that.

Comment: In this particular case there *might* be some way of generating an error via an overload of `operator&` on `MyClass`. Although I agree with the comment above that trying to prevent all user errors is never possible

Comment: If you are working at OS level, can't you make that area of memory read-only ? Anyway, making it non-copyable if it is readable is hopeless.

Comment: Don't give anybody the pointer, return from `[]` by value? Or perhaps reserve an extra element at the beginning, and return a pointer with an offset?

Comment: Try to avoid giving pointers, maybe use iterators or references instead? But same as Sam said, I also think there is no skill ceiling to ingenuity of idiots in C++. One could use e.g. LLVM parsing API and write a validation tool which checks for `delete` and its arguments. But the effort might be too high.

Comment: This seems more like an organization-related question rather than C++ question. There is literally nothing you can to prevent someone from freely messing with memory in C++. ¿Are you sure that misuse of this API with wild deletes is actually yours problem? If you have some influence on development procedures then you can introduce a review rule to disable `delete`, `operator &`, copy-initialization and so on.

Comment: If you want more foolproofness, create a rpc (grpc) service that runs your code. And send your updates to the clients using streams. Then the client code can run in your client process and they can do all the crashing they want there.

Comment: Honestly, I fail to see the issue here. Anything, any class, any type in standard library has this _vulnerability_. If idiot won't try to delete ypur class, he might try to delete a random local `std::string`.

Comment: Rename `test` to `hey_you_muppets_do_not_delete_test` or maybe `test_nonowning_ptr`.

Comment: I agree with the other that it is not really possible to write a complete save API, but a private destructor prevents deleting the object.

Comment: You could overload the delete operator for `MyClass` so that it does nothing.

Comment: @All: I am loving these comments. The return type is a std::vector, and I don't want to overcomplicate, e.g. by providing an RPC server or suchlike.

Comment: @UnholySheep, that sounds a likely possibility to prevent coders accessing the pointer. Could you do an answer with a brief example, please?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, I am already, I think, returning by value, but it doesn't stop people dereferencing the pointer to take their own "copy" that they can then abuse at will. I think I am misunderstanding your point and would appreciate more detail.

Comment: What I mean is, don't provide a getter for the whole getter, instead provide it only for individual elements, and return those by value if possible.

Comment: @various, yes this is an organisational question. We are currently recruiting and asking candidates to perform a simple task that should take only an hour or two. So far we have had 3 successes out of about 12 candidates and the time taken by the successful candidate are 9 hours, 2 hours, and 3.5 hours. One failure was a guy with 20 years experience and wanting a fairly hefty salary. I don't have the knowledge, resources, or legal werewithal to perform the necessary brain surgery to solve this "organisational" problem.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat you mean have an API to return the resource count, and another to return a reference to each individual resource by index?

Comment: Mhm, but not references to elements, rather, elements by value. Otherwise one would take the address of the reference.

Comment: I think I see. So return a list of objects that contain all non-critical data and a handle to the critical data. The problem then is making sure that the data in the returned object is updated when the underlying object changes. That would work.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to HolyBlackCat for the spark of inspiration.

The answer is...extend the pimpl idiom...which I was already using.

In the implementation of `MyClass` have a static map of the available resources. Make it so `MyClass` only contains the key of its entry in said map. The implementation of the functions in the `MyClass` interface all look up the actual instance of the resource in the map and then call the equivalent API on that instance.

The list no longer needs to be protected at all. The lookup ID is private and read only. Callers can do whatever they wish with the list and the list members without damaging the underlying data at all.